# ReDim Objects in an array vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way to do this?

```
public MyDic as new Dictionary(Of string,Object)
MyDic.Add("SomeName",new object)
' GetValue is a Extension method and uses dic.TryGetValue(...)
ReDim MyDic.GetValue("SomeName")  as New DataRow
```

what I am trying to do is to define needed variables in run-time and access them as new defined type

Is it possible at all?

Is there any other ways or suggestions to accomplish this?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Forget your current code. Explain what problem you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: @AFriend I said what I'm trying to do !!

Comment: If understand correctly, you want to specify the type at run time?

Comment: @Fabulous yes and I want to do that like I said if possible at all

Comment: If your objects inherit from a common base, you can change the dictionary to one of `Dictionary(Of String, <YourBaseClass>)` and still have it type safe to some extent. Other than that, you will have to go with Object as you have done here and determine what it is when you read it from the dictionary before proceeding accordingly. You cannot change a variable's type at run time.

Comment: @Fabulous how exactly can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Based on your comment I am modifying the answer. I'll leave the original in case anyone else understands your problem the way I did initially.

You cannot modify the return type of a method and have it flow back to your dictionary. What you can however do, is change the item directly in the dictionary.

```
Dim stuff As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
stuff.Add("SomeName", New Object())

' Later, when you have to change it.
stuff("SomeName") = 23  ' If you didn't have "SomeName" as a key, it will be created. Otherwise the value will be changed.
```

You can wrap this in an extension method as follows:

```
<Extension>
Public Sub SetValue(dic As Dictionary(Of String, Object), valueName As String, value As Object)
    If Not dic.ContainsKey(valueName) Then Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException ' Or whatever you want to do here
    dic(valueName) = value
End Sub
```

**Original** - *I initially thought you wanted to determine what type of object is there and respond accordingly.*

Rather than adding a new object and trying to change it later, just add the item you want when you have the value. When you get it back, determine what it is and process it accordingly. I have defined the dictionary the same way as you did.

```
Dim stuff As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)

stuff.Add("SomeName", 23)

Dim item = stuff.GetValue("SomeName")
If item IsNot Nothing Then
    Select Case item.GetType()
        Case Is = GetType(String)
            Console.WriteLine("String")
        Case Is = GetType(Integer)
            Console.WriteLine("Integer")
    End Select
End If
```

Without more context of what you are adding I can't provide something more concrete. You can use this to determine what do with integers, strings and the like.

I'd still recommend making it a `Dictionary(Of String, BaseClass)` or `Dictionary(Of String, IInterface)` using some base that you can safely make assumptions on what you can do with the value you get back.

Comment: I'm trying to do 'stuff.GetValue("SomeName") = 23'

Comment: @AliTheOne I have changed my answer.